# Fuse Karaf rest-dsl-simple missing

Tags: rest, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fuse

Trying the Fuse Karaf quickstarts "rest-dsl-simple" build and install in Fuse appears successful, however the tests do not. The both just say site cannot be reached.

Looking in Fuse.log I see...

```
2021-03-28 08:34:34,680 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel      | o.a.k.s.i.a.o.CommandExtension   | 152 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.2.9.fuse-780023-redhat-00001 | Command registration delayed for bundle org.apache.karaf.http.core/4.2.9.fuse-780023-redhat-00001. Missing service: [org.apache.karaf.http.core.ServletService, org.apache.karaf.http.core.ProxyService]
```

Then later I see my bundle set to failure...

```
2021-03-28 08:34:43,066 | ERROR |  Event Dispatcher: 1 | o.a.c.b.BlueprintCamelContext    | 62 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.23.2.fuse-780036-redhat-00001 | Error occurred during starting CamelContext: fusequickstart-restdsl-simple-camel
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route3: Route(route3)[[From[rest://get:/simplerest:/get?componentNam... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: restlet of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestConsumerFactory
    at
```

What feature(s) do I need to install to rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going to the http://localhost:8181/hawtio/osgi/features and filtering on REST features and installing them.  Yes I know shotgun approach but it will ensure whatever technology I choose down the road will likely be covered.

Now rest-dsl-simple fuse karaf quickstart is working and now I can move to my code, knowing the fuse-karaf engine is running normally.

:-)